# What do I do about an empty instance variable in a form helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms, form-helpers

I have two associated models where case_studies belong_to clients and clients has_many case studies.  My controller has a before_filter to find all the clients for an instance variable of @clients.

Then I have a form that allows a user to select which client the case_study belongs to.

Using a form_helper, I have the case_studies model scoped to the variable f, and some fields.

```
<div class='fields'>
  <%= f.label :case_study_title -%>
  <%= f.text_field :case_study_title -%>

  <%= f.label :which_client_does_this_belong_to? -%>
  <%= f.select(:client_id, @clients.collect{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }) -%>
</div>
```

This all work great **except** when there are no clients in my database.  I know it's because @clients is nil, and it's trying to do a collect method on nil, which will blow up.

What is the Rails way to do handle this?
Should I use exists? nil? or empty?  Should I do this right there in my erb or should I put it in a helper?  Should I do something else?

---

### EDIT to show conroller

my controller is very simple.  it has some mysterious crudify black magic from the refinerycms and I just added a before filter

```
module Refinery
  module CaseStudies
    module Admin
      class CaseStudiesController < ::Refinery::AdminController
        before_filter :find_all_clients

        crudify :'refinery/case_studies/case_study', :xhr_paging => true

    protected
        def find_all_clients
            @clients = Refinery::Clients::Client.all
        end 

      end
    end
  end
end
```

perhaps this is a terrible smell?  it's too easy not to be lol.  any advice on my hygiene is appreciated also

Comment: If you do a Model.find(:all, :conditions => {:id => 0}) or a similar #find that finds 0 records, it returns an empty Array.  What does your controller code look like?

Comment: edited original for formatting

Answer (score -1):

I think it's easy enough to just do:

```
<%unless @clients.empty?%>
<%= f.label :which_client_does_this_belong_to? %>
<%= f.select(:client_id, @clients.collect{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }) %>
```

Comment: that's what I've been doing - thanks!  i'm a noob working solo so I'm just looking for some validation and direction.  Will mark yours as the answer - want to leave it open for now in case someone else chimes in.

Comment: undefined method `empty?' for